# Can one Azure application be used for all tenants/subdomains to work with Teams SSO?

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal

We have a multitenant web app and each tenant has their subdomain:

```
a.site.com
b.site.com
c.site.com
```

Each tenant has their site/subdomain installed as an app in his Teams.

Tenants can login to their site using Azure SSO. For that we added an Azure **multitenant** application and the `Application ID URI` is the default one: `api://<Guid>`

For adding Teams SSO, we need to setup `webApplicationInfo.resource` (it really needs a domain?).

Does it mean we will have to create a new Azure application for each tenant? And will have to change their `Application ID URI` to be:

```
api://a.site.com/<Guid>
api://b.site.com/<Guid>
api://c.site.com/<Guid>
```

Question: can one Azure application be used for all tenants/subdomains to work with Teams SSO?

Comment: You don't mention if this is for a tab app or a bot app, as bots don't use a domain portion in any case. I'm presuming it's for a tab app?

Comment: Yes, it's for a tab app

Answer (score 0):

When configuring the `webApplicationInfo.resource` property in the app manifest file, you need to provide the domain of your app's subdomain URI.
In your case, it would be `a.site.com`, `b.site.com`, or `c.site.com`, depending on the tenant.

The `webApplicationInfo.resource` property ensures that the authentication request using `getAuthToken()` is from the domain specified in the app manifest.

1.Create a single Azure AD application for your web app.

2.Configure the application ID URI as `api://<subdomain>/<GUID>`, where
 represents the specific subdomain for each tenant
(a.site.com, b.site.com, c.site.com), and  is the unique
identifier for your app.

3.Configure the necessary scopes and permissions for your app's API.
Register your tab app in Azure AD and enable it for SSO by
configuring the webApplicationInfo property in the app manifest file.

4.Set the webApplicationInfo.resource property to the respective
subdomain URI (a.site.com, b.site.com, c.site.com) for each tenant.

Comment: I don't understand step 2 above, as the Azure App screen only allows for a single "Application ID URI" on the "Expose an API" screen - you can't enter multiple urls there. Can you elaborate on this please.

Comment: In theory, this can be easily achieved within one tenant, simply by setting the app to allow multiple tenants, using the "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant)" setting in the "Authentication" section on the menu. The problem is this warning: "Starting November 9th, 2020 end users will no longer be able to grant consent to newly registered multitenant apps without verified publishers.". I don't know if a normal enterprise can get around this (e.g. an widget producer (NOT an ISV) wanting suppliers and/or customers to be able to use their app).

Comment: Do you know if there's a way around this limitation in this kind of scenario? Alternatively, is there a way for the enterprise to register for an MPN, even without actually being an ISV?

Comment: Does step #2 mean we should create a new app for each subdomain?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow- What i meant is " if you have two apps that are hosted on different domains, you would need to create separate Teams app manifests for each app. Each manifest would have its own webApplicationInfo property with the id and resource elements specific to the app and its domain"